# Class 'Memcached' not found

Tags: php7, memcached

Обновил пхп с версии 7.3 до 7,4 и на одном из сайтов один код перестал работать - выдает

```
Class 'Memcached' not found
```

Переключаюсь назад на 7.3 - все работает, включаю 7.4, ошибка.
сделал поиск

```
grep -irl 'memcache' /etc/php
/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/memcached.ini
/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/memcached.ini
/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/memcached.ini
```

Ну вроде нашло его в папке 7.4 так в чем проблема то?

Он установлен, проверил, да и с 7,3 то работает

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep memcached
libcache-memcached-perl install
libmemcached-dev install
libmemcached11:amd64 install
libmemcachedutil2:amd64 install
memcached install
php-memcached install
```

Удаляю его - apt-get remove php-memcached
все проходит нормально.
Ставлю заново - apt-get install php-memcached, ставится нормально.
Делаю php -v и получаю -

> php -v PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'memcached.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/memcached.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20190902/memcached.so: undefined symbol:
>   igbinary_serialize), /usr/lib/php/20190902/memcached.so.so
>   (/usr/lib/php/20190902/memcached.so.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP 7.4.0 (cli)
>   (built: Nov 28 2019 07:27:28) ( NTS )

Comment: php info что рассказывает о memcached?

Comment: Если включить 7.3 - то много чего рассказывает, если же переключить на 7.4  - то поиск по результату выдает только memcached.ini

Answer (score 1):

В общем заново удалил мемкеш (мекешед), почистил систему от мусора, и установил заново и все стало нормально и все работает.

sudo apt-get remove pecl-memcached

sudo apt-get remove pecl-memcache

apt-get remove php-memcached

sudo apt autoremove

apt-get remove memcached netcat

dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ {print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge

apt-get install memcached netcat

apt-get install php-memcached

service php7.4-fpm restart